# confusion of array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
char[][] boardGame = new char[10][10];
// this is suppose to create an array object

for (char[] row : boardGame)
{
    Arrays.fill(row, 'a');
}
// this is suppose to fill the row in array with the char '*'
// and im using "Enhanced" for loops

for (int i = 0; i < boardGame.length; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < boardGame[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print("|" + boardGame[i][j] + "|");
    }
    // in the for loop above isn't "i" and "j" been overwrite with
    // numbers as I declare it int i = 0 and I update it if the
    // condition is true i++

    // how come it print|*||*||*||*||*|....instead of |1||2||3|...?

    System.out.println();
}
```

In the inner `for` loop above, "i" and "j" have been overwritten with numbers, as I declare it `int i = 0` and I update it if the condition is `true` `i++`.

How come it prints `|*||*||*||*||*|...` instead of `|1||2||3|...`?

Comment: What do you want us to say?

Comment: What is your question?!
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand why you expect it to print numbers instead of the asterisks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boardGame[i][j]` returns the `char` stored at index `j` in dimension `í`, and since you have filled the entire array with asterisks, that is what is printed. If you want to print the numbers, then replace `boardGame[i][j]` with `j`

I suggest you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) documentation for details on how arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

You filled your array entirely with the character `'a'`, how could you expect your code to output `|1||2||3|...` ?

If you want to print such thing, you can initialize your array like this :

```
char[][] boardGame = new char[10][10];
for (int i=0 ; i<boardGame.length ; i++)
    for (int j=0 ; j<boardGame[0].length ; j++) 
        boardGame[i][j] = Character.forDigit(j,10);
```